# Find the synonymous opposites!

Tags: word, english, language

Find a pair of English words each of which can be a noun, verb, adjective, or adverb such that:

- as nouns, adjectives, and adverbs, they're *opposite* in meaning
- as verbs, they have the *same* meaning

(I'm pretty sure the answer to this is unique.)

Comment: There are only [so many](https://onweb3.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/663/) possibilities

Comment: Ahah, I'm checking that list too, but I haven't found the pair...yet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My answer is:**

> **Best** and **Worst**.

**Explanation:**

> As verbs, they both mean to "get the better of" or "defeat" someone.
>
> As nouns, adverbs, and adjectives, they are clearly opposite.
>
> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/best?s=t
>
> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/worst?s=t

Comment: I've heard of *besting* somebody, but how does one *worst* them?

Comment: @JoeZ. Same thing. Well done, Cubicon! I'll accept, and +1 when I can.

Comment: Thanks, rand.  Joe, I've added links to definitions from dictionary.reference.com.

Comment: Is there a usage of the words as verbs *without* suffixes?

Comment: @IanMacDonald How do you mean?  To say something like "I will best you" has no suffix.

Comment: @Cubicon I guess "I will worst you" just doesn't sound like a sentence to me.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I'll admit, that usage sounds strange to a native English speaker, but every dictionary I've consulted seems to suggest that's a valid sentence.  Can't say I'll ever use it in a conversation, and if I did, I'd likely get some strange looks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> **Plump** and **Pat**

**As verbs**
Both share the meaning of "to touch with hands"

**As adverbs**
Pat means "opportunely, appropriately", while Plump means "with a heavy fall". Not exact opposites, but a heavy fall is never appropriate!

**As nouns**
Pat means "a light stroke with the hand" while Plump means "an abrupt plunge". The pain is very different, you see!

**As adjectives**
Plump means "round, with smooth edges" and Pat means "too simple, unconvincing, rough". Rough and smooth are opposites!

Comment: Not really _opposites_ (although different) as nouns, adverbs, or adjectives. Nice try though :-)